# Render after getting props

Tags: lit-element

I can't see a proper reason for a LitElement WebComponent to be rendered before having its props/attributes available. If the template needs a prop, you are forced to render a second time the component, after the first useless one. Worse than that, if your component looks like:

```
class MyComp extends LitElement
    static get properties() {
        return {
            myBigProp: {
                type: Object
        }
    render() {
        return html`<p> ${this.myBigProp.nestedProp}</p>`
}
```

you get an error for accessing `nestedProp` when `myBigProp` is `undefined`. Is there a **clean** way to avoid rendering twice this component?

Comment: Just add a condition like "return html`<p> ${this.myBigProp ? this.myBigProp.nestedProp : null}</p>`"

Comment: yeah, I wanted to avoid to fill all my components with these checks..

Comment: You can set a default value in the constructor so that the nested properties you need always have a value

Comment: "I can't see a proper reason…" The reason is that a LitElement template is just JavaScript, and in JavaScript you can't call `this.myBigProp.nestedProp` if `this.myBigProp` is `undefined`. This has always been the case in JavaScript. If you don't want to get an error, give `this.myBigProp` a value, as suggested by @AlanDávalos.

Answer (score 0):

If you already are able to set the properties you can simply define them in the constructor. Then it should be accessible at the first render.

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.myBigProp = {nestedProp:'nested value'}
}
```

However if you have to wait for them I usually make it clear that the component is loading visually by using an "initialized" property then handling it in the render function.

```
render() {
   if (!this.initialized) {
      return html`<div class='loading-reserved-zone'></div>`;
   } else {
      return html`<p>${this.myBigProp.nestedProp}</p>`
   }
}
```

Otherwise, "Optional Chaining Operator" are coming up to javascript in august 2020 which could handle your second scenario or you could technically use [this babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining.html) if you want to use it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lifecycle callback [shouldUpdate](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#shouldupdate). Return `false` until you want to render the component.

```js
shouldUpdate(changedProps) {
  return this.myBigProp != null;
}
```